# i want to store catagory name into the session variable when i click the text inside <a> tag

Tags: php, session

i want to store  category name into the session variable when i click the text inside  tag in this code instead of the clicked herf it shows the last value of the catagory retrieved in the while loop at the start
i don't want to use any javascript in this kindly tell me a solution in php

```
if($num > 0) {

    while($product = mysqli_fetch_array($queryfire)){
        #print_r($product);
?>

<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-warning">
    <a href="#"<?php $_SESSION['catagory']=$product['catagory']?>> <?php  echo $product["catagory"] ?> 
    </a> 
</li>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: $_SESSION['catagory'] holds the last value of the category retrieved because it is getting updated in the while loop.

Comment: how will i get the clicked catagory in $_SESSION['catagory']? @MadhuJayarama

Comment: if i add a code like
     href="<?php echo $_SESSION['catagory'].php" then it leads to the next page with the clicked catagory but i want it all in one page @MadhuJayarama

Comment: I have the code for this. But I can't answer this question as it is closed. Can you post an another question and tag me in that. I will be able to give the solution.

Comment: @MadhuJayarama if you have the code kinly send it to me at waleedwali27@gmail.com

Comment: Sent it to your mail. Check it out. Next time, please frame the question so that it won't be flagged as duplicate.

Comment: ok thanks for the tip and the code means the world to me @MadhuJayarama